# Why the FCM not working on ios in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

I'm Following this steps to add push notification to my app using firebase messaging but after all of this steps it doesn't work

[ios_client](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/ios/client)

[APNs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/ios/client#upload_your_apns_certificate)

```
<key>FirebaseAppDelegateProxyEnabled</key>
<false/>

final FirebaseMessaging _firebaseMessaging = FirebaseMessaging();
  void firebaseTrigger(BuildContext ctx) async {
    _firebaseMessaging.configure(
      onMessage: (Map<String, dynamic> message) async {
        print("onLaunch: $message");
        Fluttertoast.showToast(
          msg: message['notification']['title'],
          toastLength: Toast.LENGTH_LONG,
          gravity: ToastGravity.TOP,
          timeInSecForIosWeb: 6,
        );
      },
      onLaunch: (Map<String, dynamic> message) async {
        Navigator.push(
          context,
          MaterialPageRoute(
            builder: (context) => NotificationScreen(),
          ),
        );
      },
      onResume: (Map<String, dynamic> message) async {
        Navigator.push(
          context,
          MaterialPageRoute(
            builder: (context) => NotificationScreen(),
          ),
        );
      },
    );
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    firebaseTrigger(context);
    _firebaseMessaging.requestNotificationPermissions(
        const IosNotificationSettings(
            sound: true, badge: true, alert: true, provisional: true));
    _firebaseMessaging.onIosSettingsRegistered
        .listen((IosNotificationSettings settings) {
      print("Settings registered: $settings");
    });
  }
```

But the push notification doesn't work for ios only but it works on android
so kindlly can anyone help me in my problem

Edit: my appDelegate

[image]

Comment: are u runing on simulator?

Comment: check the documentation i am not familiar with ios, but go through this also https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/messaging/apple-integration

Comment: @GbengaBAyannuga no in real device

Comment: @Assassin I'm following this document but same problem

Comment: let me see your payload

Comment: @GbengaBAyannuga I'm send the notification from firebase console

Answer (score 1):

```
override func application(_ application: UIApplication, didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken deviceToken: Data) {
        let firebaseAuth = Auth.auth()
        firebaseAuth.setAPNSToken(deviceToken, type: AuthAPNSTokenType.unknown)

    }
```

add this to your appDelegate....
here is example of appDelegate

```
import UIKit
import Flutter

import Firebase
import FirebaseAuth
import UserNotifications
import FirebaseMessaging


@UIApplicationMain
@objc class AppDelegate: FlutterAppDelegate {
  override func application(
    _ application: UIApplication,
    didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?
  ) -> Bool {
    

    application.registerForRemoteNotifications()
    GeneratedPluginRegistrant.register(with: self)
    return super.application(application, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: launchOptions)
  }
  
   override func application(_ application: UIApplication, didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken deviceToken: Data) {
        let firebaseAuth = Auth.auth()
        firebaseAuth.setAPNSToken(deviceToken, type: AuthAPNSTokenType.unknown)

    }
    override func application(_ application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [AnyHashable : Any], fetchCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UIBackgroundFetchResult) -> Void) {
        let firebaseAuth = Auth.auth()
        if (firebaseAuth.canHandleNotification(userInfo)){
            print(userInfo)
            return
        }
    
    }
   
  
 
}
```

Comment: should i remove this  if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
  UNUserNotificationCenter.current().delegate = self as? UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate
} from my appDelegate and put yours ?

Comment: remove it... after adding it.... update let me see where u paste it

Comment: is this answer will make the ios notification permission appear ??